# VPN client doesn't work after updating to Mac OS 10.6 (Snow Leopard)

Tags: macos, mac, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I get the Error:

> Error 51: Unable to communicate with the VPN subsystem
>   Please make sure that you have at least one network interface that is currently active
>   and has an IP address and start this application again

I used to get that error before on Mac OS X and the work around was to restart like this:

```
/System/Library/StartupItems/CiscoVPN/CiscoVPN restart
```

but this does not seem to work anymore. In fact, the folder StartupItems appears to be empty now. I am running Cisco's VPNClient Version 4.9.01 (0080). Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you previously used the Cisco VPN Client and want to use the native Snow Leopard client, you need to un-install all of the Cisco configs, kernel extensions, etc. To do this, just run sudo /usr/local/bin/vpn_uninstall in Terminal.

Take a look here for more comments about this issue

[link text](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20090901200411622)

Comment: yeah, get rid of the cisco client and use the built in VPN in Network Preferences.